# Extract given columns from a matrix based on a vector in Matlab

Tags: matlab, matrix, extract

I have this matrix:

```
A = [2 3 5; 1 7 8; 4 9 1; 6 2 6]
```

and this vector:

```
b = [1 0 1 0]
```

And I would like to get this matrix:

```
C = [2 3 5; 4 9 1]
```

Thanks for your answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will do the job:

```
C=A(b==1,:)
```

Comment: This solution is more efficient

Answer (score 1):

you can do the following using [find](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) method

```
C = A(:,find(b))
```

Comment: Thanks. I had to change to C = A(:,find(b)) because your proposed command was getting rows instead of columns

Comment: i thought that's what you wanted sorry :p